# Zipping nested lists

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying but am unable to zip the following two lists in a particular way:

```
list1 = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]
list2 = [10,11,12]
zippedlist = [(1,2,3,10),(4,5,6,11),(7,8,9,12)]
```

I initially thought unpacking `list1` and running `zip(*list1,list2)` would do the job, but I understand now that will not work.

I suspect this can be done using one or more for-loops with the `zip` function but I'm not too sure how that'd work. Any advice on how I can proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or simply use the `+` operator in your list comprehension:

```
list1=[(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]
list2=[10,11,12]

new_list = [i+(v,) for i,v in zip(list1,list2)]

#[(1, 2, 3, 10), (4, 5, 6, 11), (7, 8, 9, 12)]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `map`:

```
list(map(lambda x, y: x +(y,), list1, list2))
# [(1, 2, 3, 10), (4, 5, 6, 11), (7, 8, 9, 12)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `zip`

**Ex:**

```
list1=[(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]
list2=[10,11,12]

result = [tuple(list(i) + [v]) for i, v in zip(list1, list2)]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[(1, 2, 3, 10), (4, 5, 6, 11), (7, 8, 9, 12)]
```

Answer (score 1):

More easy to understand is to spread the tuple and join list 2 then convert it to tuple again.

```
result = list(map(lambda x, y: (*x, y) , list1, list2))
```

result = [(1, 2, 3, 10), (4, 5, 6, 11), (7, 8, 9, 12)]